# Loading Screen WinRT c#

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, loading

I would like to have a loading screen before the launch of the app for 2 seconds. But i have no ideas how to do that. I just know i need to use a progress ring.

Anyone knows how to do this ?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create separate page called e.g. `LoadingPage` and set it as a starting page for your app. Within that page show your progress ring and do whatever you want/need to do. After 2 seconds (or when job is done) navigate into your normal starting page withing application.

Comment: I'll try this thing. But last question : how make a cooldown of 2 seconds?  Because in C# there is no setTimeout ?

Comment: with await Task.Delay(2000);

Answer (score 1):

this is what we call a SplashScreen , you need to create your own page and adding this code to your app constructor :

```
        ExtendedSplashScreenFactory =  (screen) =>
        {
            return new ExtendedSplashScreen(screen);
        };
```